# How to determine the conductivity of different chemical compounds?

Tags: ionic-compounds

I am doing an experiment that involves testing the conductivity of three different chemical compounds dissolved in water. I will be testing Potassium Chloride, Calcium Chloride and Zinc Chloride. All three will be of equal concentration. Is there any way to determine the conductivity of different chemical compounds dissolved in water? Out of these three chemical compounds, which one will be the most conductive, and why? Is there any correlation between reactivity and conductivity of chemical compounds?

Comment: In my days the word _"experiment"_ was used to denote the act of grabbing some _actual chemical compounds_  with your hands and doing something with them. If you went halfway through this process only to realize that you don't know how to perform the next measurement or whether it is possible at all, this was considered a flaw in your planning. Things might be different these days, though...

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm just asking about if there is a way to determine the conductivity by looking at the electron configuration or reactivity or something similar.

Comment: Yes, but not in the way you think. Electron configuration is irrelevant. Reactivity is not a thing at all, and irrelevant, too. Most importantly, are you doing an experiment or not? If yes, you are supposed to obtain some real measured values, and then maybe explain why they differ the way they do.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, I am doing the experiment, and this is completely unrelated to it. I'm just curious if there is a way to determine the conductivity.

Comment: Well, see which of the salts produces more ions, and that would be it.